# Exception HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request with Indy TidHttp

Tags: dll, delphi-2009, idhttp

I have a main application which calls a DLL.  This DLL is where I do my HTTP requests using Indy's `TIdHTTP` component.  It runs fine the first time, but then after closing the DLL and re-opening it, I get an `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` exception:

```
var
  idgetInfo : TIdHTTP;
begin
  idgetInfo := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  idgetInfo.AllowCookies := True;
  idgetInfo.HandleRedirects := True;
  try
    result := idgetInfo.Get(GetString);
  finally 
    if Assigned(idgetInfo) then
      FreeAndNil(idgetInfo);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with the DLL. The error means the HTTP request is malformed in some manner that the server does not accept. What does the actual request look like? Use a packet sniffer like Wireshark, or attach a `TIdLog...` component to `TIdHTTP`, to get the raw data being transmitted.

Comment: Hi Remy, this is what I get in the Indy log file... Stat Connected.
Sent 19/09/2016 10:12:46 : GET /data/2.5/find?&q=Centurion,za&units=metric&lang=en&APPID=d35df2970c30a04b5f13f84198f72aec HTTP/
Host: api.openweathermap.org
Accept: text/html, */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)


Recv 19/09/2016 10:12:46 : HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: openresty
Date: Mon, 19 Sep 2016 08:12:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 166
Connection: close

Comment: That information should have been added to your question, not posted in a comment. And there is clearly a body present in the response, does it say anything about why the request was bad?

Comment: Which Weather API are you trying to access exactly?  Looking at the available APIs on openweathermap.org, I don't see any that are accessed at `/data/2.5/find`.

Comment: I am calling 5 day / 3 hour forecast data, but there is something I have recently noticed, when doing a request the first time looking at the TidLog, the sent information has a HTTP/1.0, and then on the second try when it fails it sends just HTTP/ ...could this perhaps be the reason?